# Deleting user account when user has published articles

Tags: user, acl, joomla-4, administration

We've got a few dozens registered users on our website. They all have the right to publish, and edit articles in selected categories. Some of those users no longer need their access. So I can either block, or delete those ids. I'd prefer to delete them.

Question is about any drawback, or possible problem deleting a user might cause. Especially if that user is the author, or editor of published articles.

A quick test showed that Joomla! still displays such an article, but without showing the author. So it seems to be prepared for this case. But is there anything I didn't consider?

This is a Joomla! 4 site, if that matters at all.

Comment: It looks like you haven't earned your Informed badge yet, please take our [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the records in the Joomla database that have `created_by` or `modified_by` fields will have the same issue when you delete users in Joomla's User Manager.

I don't think that removing users will break your Joomla 4 site. However, you might want to test:

- Joomla's Contacts (**com_contact**) if there are any contact pages for those users and if they still work.
- Joomla 4's new **Workflow functionality**. If you are using it, you'd better test if everything still works after removing a user.
- **Any 3rd party extension** that uses Joomla's `userid` in their tables.

To get rid of the annoying "missing user" message in the back-end in Joomla's article manager, you could run some SQL queries to change the `created_by`/`modified_by` to another `userid`. Some SQL queries (backup your database first!) are available here: https://talikka.com/?view=category&id=8

Furthermore you could use a commercial extension **RO Users** to fix those missing users in Joomla and some 3rd party extensions: https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/ro-users/